# Android device manager for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, android

I have recently switched to ubuntu from windows and I was looking forward to get any android device managing app for Ubuntu.

I have an android tablet [celkon ct2] which has preinstalled mobogenie

I am looking foreward for any app equivalent to mobogenie of windows 7 in trusty tahr.

Comment: Ubuntu is not the same as Android. Please don't assume everybody knows what some Windows program is used for.

Comment: Have you tried airdroid?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is this Windows app? What features from it do you need?

Comment: i have clearly mentioned that i want an app with all the features of mobogenie which is an android device managing software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to manage your android from Ubuntu is to use [**AirDroid**]

There are a lot of features,
Manage your Android devices on the web, all over the air.

- No USB cable required.
- No driver installation required.
- Same WiFi network or Internet.
- Pure web app, works on Windows, Mac, Chromebook and Linux.

Simply install AirDroid on your Android and you’ll be able to enjoy the following features on your computer

- SMS: send and receive individual or group messages.
- Apps: Import and export .apk files.
- Files: Manage files on Android and transferring files between Android and computer.
- Photos: View and manage photos on Android and transferring photos between Android and computer.
- Music & Videos: Play and manage music & videos on Android and transferring them between Android and computer.
- Ringtones: Set music as ringtone and export any ringtone.
- Contacts: View and edit all the contacts.

Comment: when i get it downloaded into my tablet what should i do to connect it to my pc

Comment: open the app in your tablet, then in your computers web browser open the given address.. make sure your tablet is connected to internet or using same network that your conputer is using.